# Como remover quebra de linha de arquivo txt em array PHP

Tags: php, array, upload

Tenho um arquivo txt extraído de um PDF. Faço upload deste txt via php, e preciso retirar a quebra de linha entre os itens da descrição e colocar em um array, segue:

TXT ORIGINAL:

```
0235.000001-4 0235.213.00001295-8

`DUAS ALIANÇAS, NOVE ANÉIS, QUATRO BRINCOS, UM COLAR, SETE
PENDENTES, QUATRO PULSEIRAS, DE: OURO BRANCO, OURO, PRATA  
PALÁDIO, OURO BAIXO; CONTÉM: pedra, diamantes; CONSTAM:  
amassada(s), defeito(s), falta, iniciais, incompleta(s), inscrições,
partida(s),  PESO LOTE: 37,80G (TRINTA E SETE GRAMAS E OITENTA CENTIGRAMAS)

R$ 2.198,00 

Valor Grama: 58,15
```

RESULTADO ESPERADO DO ARRAY

```
 array
  0 =>
   array
    0 => 0235.000001-4 0235.213.00001295-8
    1 => 'DUAS ALIANÇAS, NOVE ANÉIS, QUATRO BRINCOS, UM COLAR, SETE PENDENTES, QUATRO PULSEIRAS, DE: OURO BRANCO, OURO, PRATA PALÁDIO, OURO BAIXO; CONTÉM: pedra, diamantes; CONSTAM: amassada(s), defeito(s), falta, iniciais, incompleta(s), inscrições, partida(s), PESO LOTE: 37,80G (TRINTA E SETE GRAMAS E OITENTA CENTIGRAMAS)'
    2 => R$ 2.198,00 
    3 => 'Valor Grama: 58,15'
1 =>
 array
    0 => 
    1 => 
    2 => 
    3 =>
```

Segue código que estou usando:

```
$file       = fopen($fileName,"r") or exit("Unable to open file!");

        if ( $file !== false ) {

            $i = 0;
            $members = Array();
            while (!feof($file)) {
                $string = fgets($file);
                $string = preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $string );
                $members[$i][] = $string;
            }
            var_dump($members);
            fclose($file);
        }
```

Porém não estou conseguindo colocar a descrição do lote em uma única linha do array, segue resultado do código acima:

```
array (size=1)
0 => 
array (size=30952)
  0 => string '' (length=3)
  1 => string '0235.000001-4 0235.213.00001295-8 ' (length=34)
  2 => string '' (length=0)
  3 => string 'DUAS ALIANÇAS, NOVE ANÉIS, QUATRO BRINCOS, UM COLAR, SETE  ' (length=61)
  4 => string 'PENDENTES, QUATRO PULSEIRAS, DE: OURO BRANCO, OURO, PRATA  ' (length=59)
  5 => string 'PALÁDIO, OURO BAIXO; CONTÉM: pedra, diamantes; CONSTAM:  ' (length=59)
  6 => string 'amassada(s), defeito(s), falta, iniciais, incompleta(s), inscrições, partida(s),  ' (length=84)
  7 => string 'PESO LOTE: 37,80G (TRINTA E SETE GRAMAS E OITENTA CENTIGRAMAS) ' (length=63)
  8 => string '' (length=0)
  9 => string 'R$ 2.198,00 ' (length=12)
  10 => string 'Valor Grama: 58,15 ' (length=19)
  11 => string '' (length=0)
```

Alguém poderia ajudar?

Comment: Ficou resolvida a sua questão

Comment: Você precisa tratar sua regra de negócio dentro do laço. No que você descreveu, pode considerar a linha em branco como separador dos valores que você está buscando. Para remover espaços nas extremidades de uma string utilizamos a função trim()

Comment: Trim tambem não está dando certo, pois remove os espaços mas não coloca tudo em uma unica posição no array.

Answer (score 1):

Use a função [`preg_split()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-split.php) para dividir string por uma expressão regular.

Use a sequencia de escape [`\R`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/regexp.reference.escape.php) para encontrar uma quebra de linha independente do OS em que foi gerada.

```
<?php

$texto = '0235.000001-4 0235.213.00001295-8

DUAS ALIANÇAS, NOVE ANÉIS, QUATRO BRINCOS, UM COLAR, SETE
PENDENTES, QUATRO PULSEIRAS, DE: OURO BRANCO, OURO, PRATA  
PALÁDIO, OURO BAIXO; CONTÉM: pedra, diamantes; CONSTAM:  
amassada(s), defeito(s), falta, iniciais, incompleta(s), inscrições,
partida(s),  PESO LOTE: 37,80G (TRINTA E SETE GRAMAS E OITENTA CENTIGRAMAS)

R$ 2.198,00 

Valor Grama: 58,15';

//Quebra a string nas linhas em branco independente de OS: Windows(\r\n), Linux(\n), OSX(\r)
$saida  = preg_split('#\R\s*\R#', $texto);


//Caso precise você pode remover as quebras de linha da descrição, senão comente essa linha 
$saida[1] = preg_replace('#\R+#', '', $saida[1]);

print_r($saida);
```

Código no Repl.it: https://repl.it/repls/BouncyStaidPorts

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a função explode, utilizando "\n" como quebra de linha

```
$texto = "0235.000001-4 0235.213.00001295-8  
`DUAS ALIANÇAS, NOVE ANÉIS, QUATRO BRINCOS, UM COLAR, SETE PENDENTES, QUATRO PULSEIRAS, DE: OURO BRANCO, OURO, PRATA PALÁDIO, OURO BAIXO; CONTÉM: pedra, diamantes; CONSTAM: amassada(s), defeito(s), falta, iniciais, incompleta(s), inscrições, partida(s),  PESO LOTE: 37,80G (TRINTA E SETE GRAMAS E OITENTA ENTIGRAMAS)
R$ 2.198,00 
Valor Grama: 58,15";

$array= explode("\n", $texto);
```

Comment: Utilizando explode, em cada quebra de linha da descrição, irá ser uma posição no array, qdo na verdade eu quero que a quebra de linha da descrição seja removida e fique tudo em uma posição só.